# Why is the ground not showing in the render?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

In the viewport there is the desert ground but it isn't there in the render?
[image: Rendered]
[image: Viewport]

Comment: have you checked the visibility options in the Outliner (also check the Globally disable in render option)?

Comment: @moonboots Vewport / Render is seen at screen as enabled under Outliner (if Global would disabled it would not be seen in Viewport) ... modifier?

Comment: @Henry ... probably share your file just with Desert object if issue persist. BTW How relates the title of your question with your issue?

Comment: @vklidu Sorry, was going to ask a question before this one but managed to resolve it, just forgot to change the title. 

Comment: Can't imagine how, but OK ... great you solved it ... please delete your Question or create an Answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, the particle system for the cacti was the problem. I just had to make the instances real from in the modifiers tab.